# Having issues with @media (min-width: XXXpx) working for one id but not the other

Tags: css, media-queries, css-tables

I wrote a HTML & CSS table for my companies website and almost everything is working correctly exemple for one @media css element. Funny thing is, I have used the exact CSS element correctly for almost the exact same scenario.

The id #space is transforming for mobile correctly but the id #title is not. Seems to work fine on Codepen but when I insert into the website it's not working at all. If I change the id of #title to #space it seems to take on that @media property but if I change the id to another id it does nothing again.

Any ideas? I know it's not the cleanest, but I think I have it working correctly

Here's the  CSS & HTML (CSS I'm talking about is at the very bottom)

```css
/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table.fans { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
table.fans tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee;
}

table.fans th { 
  background: #002e59; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}


table.fans td, table.fans th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}

/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table.fans, table.fans thead, table.fans tbody, table.fans th, table.fans td, table.fans tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
    
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    table.fans thead table.fans tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
    
    table.fans tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
    
    table.fans td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }
    
    table.fans td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
  
  /*
    Label the data
    */
  
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "SHROUD TYPE";}
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "FAN OPTION"; }
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "FAN/SHROUD THICKNESS"; }
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "PACKAGE THICKNESS"; }
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "SINGLE FAN $$"; }
    table.fans td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "DUAL FAN $$"; }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
   table.fans #space {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 760px) {
   table.fans #title {
        text-display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="fans">
<thead>
<tr><th>SHROUD TYPE</th><th>FAN OPTIONS</th><th>FAN/SHROUD THICKNESS (in.)</th><th>PACKAGE THICKNESS (in.)</th><th>SINGLE FAN $$</th><th>DUAL FAN $$</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>OEM STYLE SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">N/A</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">N/A</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">N/A</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$180</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">N/A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="title" style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4"><strong>BRACKET MOUNTED</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">LOW PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$160</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$295</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>BRACKET MOUNTED</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">MEDIUM PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$195</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$365</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>BRACKET MOUNTED</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">HIGH PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$215</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$405</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>BRACKET MOUNTED</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">PADDLE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$240</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$455</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4"><strong>INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">LOW PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$275</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$420</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">MEDIUM PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$310</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$490</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">HIGH PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$330</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$530</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">PADDLE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$355</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$580</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
<td id="space" style="background: #002e59;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;" rowspan="4"><strong>NON-INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">LOW PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$235</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$370</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>NON-INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">MEDIUM PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">2.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">5.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$270</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$440</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>NON-INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">HIGH PROFILE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.5"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$290</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$480</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>NON-INTEGRATED FAN SHROUD</strong></td>
<td style="text-align: center;">PADDLE FAN(S)</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">3.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">6.75"</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$315</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">$530</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ids need to be __unique__ within an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

You should use class instead of id to achieve the same result as one id should be given to only one element in a document. Try it with class and it should work.